# How to run multiple instances of webpack electron application

Tags: webpack, electron

I am building an electron application using https://webpack.electron.build

The application has network chat capabilities which i would like to test locally. I would like to be able to open 2 console windows and run yarn dev in one and yarn dev2 in the other to cause electron to start up 2 distinct instances of my app that don not share any local storage or dev servers etc.  How do i configure the  dev2 script?